# Inno Setup: Combo box closing immediately on drop-down (which starts an application)

Tags: combobox, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am getting a list of Application Pools and then populating the combo box with the names of app pools. The problem is that when when the `OnDropDown` event is called the combo box opens for a fraction of a second and then closes straight away. It does not remain "dropped down". I do see all the app pools in the combo box. Here is my code:

```pascal
function GetApplicationPoolList() : TArrayOfString;
var
  i, nExitCode: Integer;
  sFileLines: TArrayOfString;
  sTempFileName, sListAppPoolCmd: String;  
begin

    sListAppPoolCmd := ExpandConstant('{sys}') + '\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /text:name'; 
    sTempFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\appPoolList.txt';
    if not ExecAppCmd(Format('%s > %s',[sListAppPoolCmd, sTempFileName]), nExitCode) then begin
      MsgBox('Could not get app pools', mbError, MB_OK);
    end else begin      
      LoadStringsFromFile(sTempFileName, sFileLines);
    end
    Result := sFileLines;
end;

// ==============================================

procedure OnAppPoolComboBoxDropDown(Sender: TObject);
var
  sAppPoolList: TArrayOfString;
  i: Integer;
begin

  // Clear existing
  appPoolComboBox.Items.Clear;
  // Populate the combo box with the application pools
  sAppPoolList := GetApplicationPoolList;  

  For i := 0 to GetArrayLength (sAppPoolList) - 1 do
    begin
      // ComboBox with Application Pool Names   
      appPoolComboBox.Items.Add(sAppPoolList[i]);      
    end;
  appPoolComboBox.ItemIndex := 0;
end;


function ExecAppCmd(params :String; nExitCode: Integer) :Boolean;
var
  execSuccessfully :Boolean;
  resultCode :Integer;
begin
  execSuccessfully := Exec('cmd.exe', '/c ' + '' + ' ' + params, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultCode); 
  nExitCode := resultCode;   
  Result := execSuccessfully and (resultCode = 0);
end;
```

I am not sure what is happening here. Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: `ExecAppCmd` seems to be the issue, commenting it out makes the combo box behave normally... Though not sure why

Comment: ExecAppCmd seems to be the issue, commenting it out makes the ComboBox behave normally... Though not sure why....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop-down closes probably because the combo box loses focus momentarily as the application is starting.

I'd say it's a bad practice to call an application on drop-down, as it takes time and it ruins a user experience. Populate the combo box earlier, like from `CurPageChanged`.

Comment: Thanks... Yes when the cmd.exe finished the combo box would lose focus and hence close. I have changed it to be done on page load.